# 2007 Jeep commander, car blows hot (extremely) air

Tags: jeep, hvac, commander

Had actuator as well as controll head replaced and car still blows hot air.  When controls are in off position hot air will blow in.  Turn ac on hot air still blows in.  Been to two Jeep dealers and both unable to solve problem

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If you paid them to solve it and they have not - take it back or get your money back...